# SQL MIN(value) matching date

Tags: sql, mysql

Alright I have a table where I need to get the relevant date from a GROUP BY function...

```
Here is a sample of the data:
min_price, day
140000     2010-09-26
130000     2010-09-27
154991     2010-10-08
143000     2010-10-09
156470     2010-10-10

I would like this result:
130000     2010-09-27
143000     2010-10-09

Here is the SQL I use:

SELECT MIN(min_price) AS low_price, min_price, day
FROM compress
WHERE item_name = '$item'
GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM day), EXTRACT(YEAR FROM day)

Here is what I get:
130000     2010-09-26
143000     2010-10-08
```

As you can see, the dates don't match up with the min row value. I need them to match up. What SQL can I use to get that result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select C.min_price, C.day
From compress As C
Where C.item_name = '$item'
    And Exists  (
                Select 1
                From compress As C2
                Where C2.item_name = C.item_name
                    And Extract(Month From C2.day) = Extract(Month From C.day)
                    And Extract(Year From C2.day) = Extract(Year From C.day)
                Group By Extract(Month From C2.day), Extract(Year From C2.day)
                Having C.min_price = Min(C2.min_price)
                )
```

**ADDITION**

MySQL is better with joins so here's a variant of the same query

```
Select C.min_price, C.day
From compress As C
    Join    (
            Select C2.item_name
                , Extract(Month From C2.day) As ItemMonth
                , Extract(Year From C2.day) As ItemYear
                , Min(C2.min_price) As MinPrice
            From compress As C2
            Group By C2.item_num, Extract(Month From C2.day), Extract(Year From C2.day)
            ) As Z
        On Z.item_name = C.item_name
            And Z.ItemMonth = Extract(Month From C.day)
            And Z.ItemYear = Extract(Year From C.day)
            And Z.MinPrice = C.min_price
Where C.item_name = '$item'
```

What is really slowing down any variation is the calling of Extract on every row. If you had a calendar table containing a row for each date and a column for the month and year of the date and your calendar table covered the date ranges in your data, you could then do something like:

```
Select C.min_price, C.day
From compress As C
    Join Calendar As Cal
        On Cal.Date = C.Day
    Join    (
            Select C3.item_name
                , Cal3.Month, Cal3.Year
                , Min(C3.min_price) As MinPrice
            From compress As C3
                Join Calendar As Cal3
                    On Cal3.Date = C3.day
            Group By C3.item_num, Cal3.Month, Cal3.Year
            ) As Z
        On Z.item_name = C.Item_name
            An Z.Month = Cal.Month
            And Z.Year = Cal.Year
            And Z.MinPrice = C.min_price
Where C.item_name = '$item'
```

Comment: Hmmm... It seems to work fine, although it is incredibly slow... I might have to find another alternative... Thank you, though.

Comment: Quick question... would there be a way to specify only certain item names with this query?

Comment: @Yoshiyahu - I've provided a couple of variants that might be faster than a subquery. In all three variations, I provided for passing a $item value into the query.

Comment: Wow. The first one works perfectly. The one with Joins doesn't pull up any rows, though. Thank you!

Comment: @Yoshiyahu - I noticed a typo in my second query. I did not also group by item_name. I've fixed that which might account for the zero row result.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT min_price AS low_price, min_price, day
FROM compress
WHERE item_name = '$item' AND min_price = MIN(min_price)
GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM day), EXTRACT(YEAR FROM day)
```

This will then select the row where the min_price is the same as the MIN(min_price)

Comment: Aggregate functions cannot be used in a WHERE clause, and it doesn't return anything with a HAVING clause. I already tried that...

Comment: Then go for Thomas's nested SELECT solution. I'll have to admit a nested SELECT was my first thought but I thought a more efficient solution would be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL is not valid.  When grouping, every column in the display list (that is not part of the group by expression) must be passed through an aggregate function, e.g. AVG(), MIN(), MAX() but you're just asking for "day".

Please state in natural language (English) what you are trying to achieve. Your example is not perfectly clear.

Comment: Ah, what I am trying to do is get the day that the min_price was at it's lowest each month. Simple as that.

Comment: Ah, it is not as simple as you think it is. What if the product remained at its lowpoint for several days running? Do you want the first day of the series or the last?

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood the problem correctly, this should work...

```
mysql> select * from stack;
+-----------+------------+
| min_price | myday      |
+-----------+------------+
|    140000 | 2010-09-26 | 
|    130000 | 2010-09-27 | 
|    154991 | 2010-10-08 | 
|    143000 | 2010-10-09 | 
|    156470 | 2010-10-10 | 
+-----------+------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select a.* from stack as a inner join 
    -> (select min(min_price) as my_price from stack group by extract(YEAR_MONTH from myday)) as b
    -> on a.min_price = b.my_price;
+-----------+------------+
| min_price | myday      |
+-----------+------------+
|    130000 | 2010-09-27 | 
|    143000 | 2010-10-09 | 
+-----------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

You will need to join on a primary key in order to avoid unexpected results. If the query is slow, create a temporary table for subselect, build indexes on it and then use the table to join with the main table.